# Can I find exoplanets without a telescope?

Tags: observational-astronomy, exoplanet

I would like to know please whether or not I can look for exoplanets without a telescope.

Comment: Although this looks like a strange question at first sight, it has actually some importance from a philosophic point of view at least.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** With a probability nearly equal 1 you will not find any exoplanet with naked eye from Earth, even under perfect conditions like no light-pollution. The human eye simply does not have enough resolution to observe any of the [closest exoplanets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_exoplanets) directly.

Neither of the [methods of detection an exoplanet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_detecting_exoplanets) work without any additional tool (such as a telescope for any part of the spectrum).